# Log table using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create trigger which insert into dbo.Log table values:
- in action_type : how many records was UPDATED ,DELETED or INSERTED
- in datetime_of_action ofcourse timestamp of action

For now I have this:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Log

CREATE TABLE dbo.Log (
logid       INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY,
action_type NVARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
datetime_of_action  DATETIME        NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Log PRIMARY KEY(logid));

CREATE TRIGGER trig2
ON Sales.Customers 
FOR UPDATE , DELETE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
......................
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.Log
```

And this is a script of Sales.Customers table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Sales].[Customers](
    [custid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [companyname] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [contactname] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [contacttitle] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [region] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [postalcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [country] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [nvarchar](24) NOT NULL,
    [fax] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [custid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

If anyone knows how do this I am open on your advice.

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not satisfy what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig2
    ON Sales.Customers 
    AFTER UPDATE , DELETE, INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (select * From inserted)
      BEGIN
       IF EXISTS (select * From deleted)
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.Log (action_typ, datetime_of_action )
            VALUES(CAST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) as VARCHAR(50) + ' records have been updated',GETDATE())
         END
       ELSE 
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.Log (action_typ, TOTAL, datetime_of_action )
            VALUES(CAST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) as VARCHAR(50) + ' records have been iniserted',GETDATE())
         END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Log (action_typ, TOTAL, datetime_of_action )
        VALUES(CAST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) as VARCHAR(50) + ' records have been deleted',GETDATE())
    END
    END
```

Comment: Make any wording changes to your real case

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue of capturing how many records are impacted.

Comment: @dfundako, please check the `log` table schema before giving comment

Comment: From the post: in action_type : how many records was UPDATED ,DELETED or INSERTED

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig2
ON Sales.Customers 
FOR UPDATE , DELETE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

-- First determine the action 
DECLARE @Action NVARCHAR(50);
SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                    THEN N'Update: ' + CAST( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                    THEN N'Insert: ' + CAST( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) AS NVARCHAR(10))
                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                    THEN N'Delete: '  + CAST( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED) AS NVARCHAR(10))
                    ELSE NULL -- Skip. It may have been a "failed delete".   
                END)

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Log] (action_type, datetime_of_action)
    VALUES (@Action , GETDATE());

END
```